EMS messages going in loop in queue in case of exception
We are consuming messages from the queue.
Currently XSD validation is failing due to incorrect data present in the XML.
When such message comes our application has catch block which is throwing below exception -

org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB
unmarshalling exception; nested exception is
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

with linked exception:


Now these messages are still present in the queue and they are not getting flushed out.
The same message keeps on coming and hence it blocks all the other messages present in the queue. This leads to accumulation of thousand of messages on the queue.
Can anyone explain how can we fix such issue.

if messages are still in the queue most likely no consumers setup for the queue that can reed the message.  adding expiration to the message may help if you don't need to reed the error messages.
